# dispatcher invoke async await .net 4.6.1

Tags: wpf, async-await

I am targeting WPF .NET 4.6.1.
I am constantly doing this:

```
btnClick
{
Task T1 = Task.Run<List<Double>>( AsyncFunction );
T1.Wait(.1);
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { txtStatus.Text+="HOLD ON.."; };
T1.Wait(.1);
}
```

The only way I can get this to actually update the UI between these Wait(s) is to do:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=>{}),priority: DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
```

Is this right? Is this portable? Describe discuss different approaches on different platforms (UWP, Windows 10 Phone).

Possibly see Raymond Chen: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190327-00/?p=102364

I explicity do not want to use Async Button Event because I need to be able to help the user, at least put logic for a tenth of a second completion check and not have the user slamming the async button handler trying to get results and congesting my sensor network with data.

You know I eventually want to get the result of this too, and process it, IN THE SAME EVENT HANDLER CODE, so like I don't want to use BackroundWorker and then have the user have to Click another button to poll the Results, which may STILL BE EMPTY and make everybody REALLY REALLY MAD.  And I don't want to Poll the results automatically and then poll the sensors network again and cause MORE congestion.

Comment: It's not "right" in that the approach seems worse than using async await. Maybe with some busy flag if you want to avoid a second click before a long process the button starts has completed. If that's what the requirement is.

Comment: @Andy I am using async await, I am doing Task Run, and mostly I just await network data in my function.  My question is about the dispatcher.  I thought I could invoke and the UI thread would, during any context switch between my synchronous Wait calls update the textbox for me. But it doesn't until I exit the button click event totally.  Or do that idle stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an interim update, my testing indicates that both async event handlers and small synchronous Wait(s) are both appropriate approaches.  I am achieving significantly better initial response by delegating only Wait(.1) to the network operation, initiating a DispatcherInvoke(()=>{txtStatus+="WAIT.."} and immediately followed by Dispatch(() =>{;//}, DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle).

Using an async event handler, and IProgress (you don't even need Dispatcher, just alter a bound control) inside the network call results in similar progress update, but with an initial response that may not be acceptable.

Using the synchronous waits results in a stalling of the UI Paint that makes any gradually updating progress bar appear very jerky.

For me, the progress bar being jerky is not the issues, because I am giving the operator direct feedback with WAIT.. WAIT .. WAIT ..And all the progress bar is doing is showing, by stalling, how backed up the thing is, but I retain enough synchronous control to jam an oscillating CAUTION in there.  The oscillation may be jerky but trained operators will know, if that CAUTION keeps toggling, however unevenly, you are on, even if the gradual progress bar stalls and starts.

And, I can detect this in synchronous code, and then do something about it on the fly, like, offload the whole network call and then force the user to queue and poll.

UPDATE

```
async Task<List<Double>> NetworkList(IProgress<Int32> NetworkProgress)
{
List<Double> _results = new List<Double>();
foreach(var aNetwork in LotsOfNetworksCouldTakeAwhile)
{
SendPingFarAwayLand();
await Task.Delay(delay: TimeSpan.Frommilliseconds(100);
Double PingTime = GetPingTimeOrNull();
_results.Add(PingTIme);
NetworkProgress.Report( aNetwork.NetworkID );
}
}


async btnClick
{
TimeSpan IDLE_LONG_ENOUGH_SO_DISPATCHER_UPDATES_UI = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
txtStatus += "WORKING...";
await Task.Delay(delay: IDLE_LONG_ENOUGH_SO_DISPATCHER_UPDATES_UI);
Task<List<Double>> results = await NetworkList(_Progress);
dependencyObject1.ObservableList1.Add(results);
return;
}
```

This seems to work at least on my computer. About 50 millis is enough to guarantee the dispatcher processes your latest "WORKING..." message immediately.  If you don't, you may hit the dispatcher on an up cycle, but maybe not, and it will start on LongNetworkList and it may be a half second before you even see that something is happening.

It's almost like do you want the sprint team captain to hit the stopwatch, or run with you.  Delay of 50 millis to even start on the work seems like a lot if you are trying to ping two sub 10ms networks.  But if you have even one aberrant one in there that immediately takes up the whole 100ms await and STILL doesn't return anything for you to report progress on, it's nice to have put up something on the screen.

Kudos to Cleary, I'm switching to Reactive.NET, right after lunch.

Comment: Any thought on this? 50 millis await after a textbox update inside async button handler does the magic?  Whats the spec on that?

Comment: See Stephen Cleary's informed and incisive upvoted comments.  My final consideration is that executing an IDLE task to the Dispatcher, just like trying to alter the Garbage Collector's housekeeping, is probably very bad for overall performance, forcing it to re-evaluate hundreds of Paint messages that are not due for another 800ms.

Answer (score 0):

> I explicity do not want to use Async Button Event because I need to be able to help the user, at least put logic for a tenth of a second completion check and not have the user slamming the async button handler trying to get results and congesting my sensor network with data.

The easiest solution is to do it the way everyone else solves it: disable the button while the operation is in progress.

```
async btnClick
{
  btn.Enabled = false;
  try
  {
    txtStatus.Text += "HOLD ON..";
    var result = await Task.Run(() => AsyncFunction());
    ... // update UI with result.
  }
  finally { btn.Enabled = true; }
}
```

Comment: Ok, a possibility, I actually don't want to do this because certain operators I still want them to be able to get at the Button 4 or five times.  This doesn't really answer my question though, I need to know about the Empty Action delegate and Dispatcher Priority Idle

Comment: This is good advice Andyz. Usually this would be a command rather than click handler.    Your post seems to indicate stopping the user clicking a second time whilst processing is still happening is necessary.  Which is usual. Now you say sometimes you don't want to do that.  Which is unusual.  Sounds kind of risky.

Comment: @Andy I need to make a decision in synchronous code.  I need the round trip time and how many came back so I can decide for most cases, most operators,-- to throttle sensor requests,-- but usually I just want to update the UI between 50ms network awaits.  And like as soon as I decide to throttle I need to start an immediate new request, time it, update the UI urgently, and then fire a background queue to possibly collect the results if the user isn't just sitting there slamming Poll.  So I need the dispatcher to work. And I don't want go back async button and relinquish to paint UI.

Comment: @AndyzSmith: I think System.Reactive would be a much better solution. Back in the day, I used `async` to tame a 20Hz device input, but I think Rx would have been cleaner (it didn't exist at the time). Regardless, the dispatcher and `Task.Wait` are the wrong tools to use here.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you.  I just feel like it should work.  In my AsyncFunction, I request and read the network, and I get to await back 100ms, 200ms at a time to the calling function, but still schedule my continuation to do minimal processing of the successful read.  And then in my controller function, I get to easily script with Task.Wait what my expectations are, and then, be able to give exclusive polling access to my function, AND be able to schedule another, lower priority call between Waits.  And I should be able to show a progress/Congestion graph/Caution light on the UI that is

Comment: current up to the latest 100ms Task.Wait.  But the Dispatcher doesn't seem to really work that way.  And I wonder about the IDLE task whether that is portable or even realiable on the platform I'm using.  Is there some specification or normative reference I can see where I know I need to Push these updates to the UI and I need synchronous control to do my next Task, but I want the UI to take as long as it needs to process whatever it has?

Comment: I still don't see the need for synchronous control. Bear in mind that Windows is not a realtime OS to begin with; 100ms waits are OK but certainly not precise; I'd expect wakeups from 80-120ms. Dispatcher is even less reliable since it is dependent on how many Win32 messages your app is getting at the time.

Comment: Yeah, I know, variable wakeups, UI busy doing some unnecessary spinning gears.  I just want control of the UI back, so for my smart operators I can put a DEFCON on there.  I need to do the absolute best possible to jam that "WAIT" on the screen, to jam that "WAIT DEFCON1" on there.  If I don't people will abort and cause more congestion.  Or hit the button again and cause congestion.  And the uninitiated user has no idea of the dynamics of this, that during high usage, it is NOMINAL for it to take a whole second. But If I can actively show more and more excited messages most people.

Comment: will get it.  And I can't wait until the second goes by, I need the UI message pump to respond to me, just to update the DEFCON Textbox.  Will it respond in 200ms or 400ms? Just have it do the best it can.  Most people will fiddle the mouse around and Hey I'm locked, and then they see DEFCON 99 on there and well they'll get it.